How to make this while loop to stop?
When I run the code the while loop it is supposed to stop when number = 2 but it never stops. I use github codespace to run code
import time
import random
Get = 0
Trys = 0

while Get == 0: 
    time.sleep(0)
    Trys = Trys + 1
    Number = str(random.randint(1, 2))
    print(Number, Trys)
    if Number == 2:
        break
print("finished")


The loop condition is while Get == 0, and the variable Get is not changed inside the loop, so of course it runs forever...

Number = str(random.randint(1, 2)) Since you used str(), Number will be a string, so if Number == 2 will never be true.  Did you mean if Number == "2" ?

Why are you using str() anyway?  There's no need, as far as I can see.

"how to make this while loop stop" The first thing is to state clearly in words when the loop should stop. It looks like you have done that: "it is supposed to stop when number = 2". However, your code checks the value of Get. If you want to stop when Number == 2, then maybe something like while Number < 2: or while Number != 2: would be more accurate to your verbal description.

There are several problems with your code. First of all you say

it is supposed to stop when number = 2

You should use this directly in the while condition rather than an if:
while Number != 2

This clearly states your intent rather than using the Get variable. Now you can get rid of the if statement.
Next, you set Number to a string:
    Number = str(random.randint(1, 2))

Instead, just use the numerical value directly:
    Number = random.randint(1, 2)

Again, use the code that most directly matches your words and your thinking. Converting a number to a string almost always adds more complexity than you need. The primary reason to do this kind of conversion is when you need to display a number. Other than that, you should use numerical values directly.
Putting this all together, the new version of your code looks like this:
import random

Trys = 0
Number = 1

while Number != 2: 
    Trys = Trys + 1
    Number = random.randint(1, 2)
    print(Number, Trys)
print("finished")

Note, I also removed the time.sleep() because it is unnecessary.

I found the problem with your code. When you declare the variable Number, you convert it to a string.
However, later in your if statement, you compare it with an integer instead of a string.
All you have to do is add quotation marks around the 2:
import random
Get = 0
Trys = 0

while Get == 0: 
    Trys = Trys + 1
    Number = str(random.randint(1, 2))
    print(Number, Trys)
    if Number == "2":
        break
print("finished")

In addition, time.sleep(0) does nothing in your code, because you are telling it to wait for 0 seconds (which makes it not wait at all).

The Number variable doesn't really need to be a string, however

import time
import random
Get = 0
Trys = 0

while Get == 0: 
    time.sleep(0)
    Trys = Trys + 1
    Number = random.randint(1, 2)
    print(Number, Trys)
    if Number == 2:
        break
print("finished")

remove str() then it will work
